# How to decrypt AES without CBC in python?

Tags: java, python

```
private static char[] encrypt(String pass) throws Exception  {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, AES_KEY);
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(pass.getBytes())).toCharArray();
}
```

how I can decrypt this password in python ? I can not find any method without CBC mode

Answer (score 0):

The SunJCE provider uses `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` if mode and padding are omitted 
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#ciphertrans)

There's an example for Python using that characteristics at https://gist.github.com/forkd/7ed4a8392fe7b69307155ab379846019
which can be easily adapted:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from base64 import b64encode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


# Padding 
BLOCK_SIZE = 16  # Bytes
pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * chr(BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE)
unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[len(s) - 1:])]


class AESCipher:
    """
    Usage:
        c = AESCipher('key').encrypt('message')
        m = AESCipher('key').decrypt(c)
    Tested under Python 3
    """

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key.encode('utf8')

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = pad(raw)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        return b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_ECB)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc)).decode('utf8')


## MAIN
# Test...
msg = 'This is a plain text...'
key = '12345678901234567890123456789012'
encrypt = AESCipher(key).encrypt(msg)
decrypt = AESCipher(key).decrypt(encrypt)
decryptFromJava = AESCipher(key).decrypt('hL1oPPxKbt2unCPyAWlZsWZO3HH/lg8DJ6eLdpYZjnxFBb85OLUxaM/G7ZXUHI0JOiBVpFd6UFcwJ5Ut65i3/rJf+DFz+T8wH/Og+9cz/ebOmvHirTfB1emsIyyKRZvx')

print('Ciphertext:', encrypt)
print('Decryted text:', decrypt)
print('Decryted text from Java:', decryptFromJava)
```

The output is:

```
Ciphertext: b'hL1oPPxKbt2unCPyAWlZsSXmQCzpJcEl1LPNmzVuL0o='
Decryted text: This is a plain text...
Decryted text from Java: This is a plain text encrypted with the Java encrypt-method which needs to be encypted...
```

whereas

`hL1oPPxKbt2unCPyAWlZsWZO3HH/lg8DJ6eLdpYZjnxFBb85OLUxaM/G7ZXUHI0JOiBVpFd6UFcwJ5Ut65i3/rJf+DFz+T8wH/Og+9cz/ebOmvHirTfB1emsIyyKRZvx`
is the encrypted output of the Java encrypt-method for the text `This is a plain text encrypted with the Java encrypt-method which needs to be encypted...`
(with the 32 Byte key: `12345678901234567890123456789012`)

which, thankfully, can also be tested without much effort with e.g. https://tio.run/#python3.